# Treeview throws Exception after upgrading to KendoUI 2013.1.319

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have problems with the KendoUI Treeview after upgrading to the latest version of KendoUI.

Sample Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var node1, node2;
function onSelect(e) {
    node1 = e.node;
    addViews();
}

function addViews() {
if (node1 != null) {
   var treeview1 = $("#TreeAvailable").data("kendoTreeView");
   var treeview2 = $("#TreeSelected").data("kendoTreeView");
   treeview1.remove(node1);      // *JavaScript Error as soon I remove the node*
}
}
```

I'm getting a JavaScript Error "Unable to get property 'set' of undefined or null reference" after calling *treeview1.remove(node1)* in kendo.web.min.js.

Debugger stops at:

```
return arguments.length?(n=e(n,r).closest(P),r.find(".k-state-selected").each
(function(){vare=i.dataItem(this);e.set("selected",!1),delete e.selected})
```

What has changed in the latest version of KendoUI? And how can I resolve it?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to remove the node being selected. After you remove the node, KendoUI still continues doing things and tries to select the node that you remove (it does no longer exist).

You should invoke `preventDefault` as in:

```
function onSelect(e) {
    node1 = e.node;
    addViews();
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

To do not let KendoUI doing things.